# Creating table from other multiple tables with joins T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a task to do. It's in polish but i will try translate it:
Merge (tables): Towar, KasTow, Notatki (Notatki.tekst replace characters '20' into XC).

so far i merged those tables, but i dont know how to put them into new table.

```
select *
from towar
left join kastow on towar.towid = kastow.kasaid
left join notatki on kastow.kasaid = notatki.towid
```

i tried few methods to put this into new table but non of them works.
for example:

```
select *
into nt
from towar
left join kastow on towar.towid = kastow.kasaid
left join notatki on kastow.kasaid = notatki.towid
```

and

```
create table nt
as select *
from towar
left join kastow on towar.towid = kastow.kasaid
left join notatki on kastow.kasaid = notatki.towid
```

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them worked"? The second query would have created the table `nt`, **provided** that none of the tables in the `FROM` had a column with the same name. But if they did, you would have got an error telling you that is the problem...

Comment: I know, and that's the problem. I need to create a new table with all conect included in those 3 tables and i dont know how to do it

Comment: *"I know, and that's the problem."* That they have the same column names? Don't use `*`, *define* your columns and their names.

Comment: Just noticed that both `towar` and `notatki` have a column called `towid`, so yes, all the above will fail; you can't have 2 columns in the same table called `towid`. They will need different names, or you will need to not expose one of the column in the `SELECT` (as by definition of your `JOIN` they *should* have the same value).

Comment: yup, they have some columns with same names.  "Don't use *, define your columns and their names" There is A LOT of columns, and defining every column 
individually will take ages

Comment: *"There is A LOT of columns, and defining every column individually will take ages"* That doesn't change that's what you should (need to) be doing. Without offence, laziness isn't an excuse for code failures. :) Take the time to list the columns you need in your `SELECT`  and the 2nd SQL statement will work.

Comment: I know i know, but its mine second day of learning sql, and im operating with very large database of big company. The person who give me this task told me, that its way to do it in fast way and i need to find it

Comment: You ***can't*** use `*` with an `INTO` when 2 columns have the same name; end of story. Define your columns, fix the problem; like you should be doing anyway. If you *really* don't want to expand `*` yourself, then purchase an add-in for SSMS, or your preferred IDE, such as SQL Prompt.

Comment: What about "create table as"? Is this working in T-SQL?

Comment: @SebastianRubacha, SQL Server does not yet support CTAS (Create Table As Select). The `INTO` syntax is how Microsoft implemented that functionality.

Comment: You may not need a table at all. Perhaps a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15) would fulfill the requirement.